# Pattern finding in a list of character vectors

Tags: r, parsing, pattern-matching

There are vectors with characters of differing length like:

```
f1 <- c("YTOI", "JKLO", "POLI")
f2 <- c("KOPL", "KOPL", "KOPL")
f3 <- c("JNLI", "NJLI", "IUYP")
f4 <- c("FIPN", "JHPL", "UIPE")
```

They are in a list as `fe <- list(f1,f2,f3,f4)`. The entries don't all have to be length 3 - could be varying.

How to find those entries (index) where all entries are identical?

Answer (score 4):

Using `lengths()`:

```
which(lengths(sapply(fe, unique)) == 1)
```

[Note:](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lengths.html)

> One raison d'être of lengths(x) is its use as a more efficient version
>   of sapply(x, length) and similar *apply calls to length.

Answer (score 3):

```
which(sapply(fe, function(x) length(unique(x))==1))
## [1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `uniqueN`

```
 library(data.table)
 which(sapply(fe, uniqueN)==1)
```